# how can I stop mac xcode automatic downloads

Tags: xcode

How can I stop xcode (11GB) downloading on my imac in catalina?
The download is shown in launchpad each time I boot up.
Stopping downloads in App Store has no effect.
I can find nothing in System Preferences to stop this download.

Answer (score 0):

Stop automatic app updates, and app update downloads in App Store > preferences.

If that doesn't stop it, delete Xcode and download it from https://developer.apple.com